# adding more RAM to an IBM Power7 server

Tags: ibm-server

I want to add more RAM to IBM server 8205-E6C (supporting now up to 256GB) 
is there any step required in ASMI interface after the additional DIMMs are installed in the server and server is powered on into standby mode?

Do I need some special activation of extra RAM or I will see new size of installed RAM just after  server starts up with it?

Can I use new RAM immediately (after server is powered with it) for increasing desired/max Memory size in old/previously created LPARs or old LPARs will have to be recreated somehow to learn new size of available/installed RAM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

8205-E6C requires no memory activation's.  Just make sure you have the correct memory carrier's to expand your memory slots (EM01).  No additional steps are necessary after adding them for turning the memory on it will just work. Assuming this is managed by an HMC follow this :https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/TI0003M/p8hat/p8hat_changeprofilep6.htm